# Show that $f^t \circ f^t=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

Let $V$ be vector space over a field $K$ and let $f$ be a linear operator on $V$. 
Suppose that $f \circ f=0.$

Show that $f^t \circ f^t=0.$

Is this really as simple as noting that $f^t \circ f^t=(f\circ f)^t=0$ or is there more to it than that?

Comment: is V finite dimensional ?

Comment: @SoumikGhosh Yes $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: then that's all there is to it.